# Changing css on elements within specific pages

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the CSS on specific elements inside the page (since I need them to be different on specific pages) Trying to do this to no avail.

```
<script>
 $(document).find('#nav-icon span').css({
    'background-color': '#333'
 });

 $(document).find('.screen-nav li a').css({
    'color': '#fff'
 });

 $(document).find('.screen-nav li a:after').css({
    'background-color': '#fff'
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you upload HTML code?

Comment: You should pass a different class to the body & then write the CSS above. I think this is a more better way.

Comment: Does it really need to be in js?

Comment: I just want this applied on the index page only. However, my header.php page applies to all pages so I can't put it in the style sheets. So I would hardcode it into the index.php directly

Comment: Your code is running before DOM is ready and therefore need to be within `$(document).ready({})`..

Answer (score 1):

However you are trying to find the html element from `document` which runs before DOM is ready. Therefore you need to bind you `find` function after DOM is ready and jquery script should be with in document.ready function and try to change css property from jQuery like this:

HTML

```
<nav class="screen-nav">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">BB</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CC</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">DD</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.screen-nav li a').css({
     "background-color": "yellow",
     "font-size": "200%",
     "color":"#000"
   });
 });
```

Working demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/eznbutwy/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to execute these CSS changes after the document has completed loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).find('#nav-icon span').css({
   'background-color': '#333'
  });
});
```

You can also reduce the code above to simply query the objects from the class. Since your parent object is the document, you can directly use JQuery selectors on the CSS classes

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav-icon span').css({
   'background-color': '#333'
  });
});
```

Comment: I have to put it on the index page directly and was told the 'find' method works best